# For each element with a certain attribute - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to find all elements whith a particular attribute. For each elements, I want to do something dependant of the value of the attribute.

I did a test to take back the value of the attribute but it doesn't work and I don't see the problem.

HTML:

```
<div id="t">Test</div>
<div data-test="One">Value One</div>
<div data-test="Two">Value Two</div>
```

JS:

```
$("[data-test]").each(function(){
    $("#t").append(this.attr("data-test"));
});
```

JsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/fbue5dpc/

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in your `each` block refers to the DOM element which does not have the `attr` method. You should use `$(this)` to convert it to a jQuery object. You can also improve this further by using the `data` method to retrieve the values and caching the `#t` element to reduce the number of DOM retrievals being made:

```
var $t = $('#t')
$("[data-test]").each(function(){
    $t.append($(this).data('test'));
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fbue5dpc/3/)

Comment: Thank you for the improvement.

Answer (score 2):

```
var elemnt = $("[data-test]"),frag = "";

elemnt.each(function () {
    frag += $(this).attr("data-test");
});
$("#t").append(frag);
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fbue5dpc/4/)**

Comment: You either should not change the `selector` or you should explain why you changed `[data-test]` to `div[data-test]`.

Comment: t.niese y dont u give answer rather than commenting and judging others answers ..let it be made by OP...

Comment: For the div, I understand the logic. However in my app, the data-test attribute can be on different elements (h1, p, ...)

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool there is nothing wrong with only commenting on the answers of others. If the OP is inexperienced they could potentially choose answers which would lead to more problems (not that I'm saying it would in this case), which is why others comment on answers to offer guidance.

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool why should I add an additional answer if `RoryMcCrossan` already gave a perfectly fine answer with an explanation. SO is not only a place where people get help as individuals, but ideally is a place to help others in future with similar question. So whenever the code of the OP is changed it might look like it is important to solve the problem. I rarely give down-votes. But I always add an comment if it believe a part of the answer can be improved.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Its not bad to comment on others answers but only commenting on others is what i felt strange..and that too bit out of box comments... anyways cheers for your correct answer..

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$(this).attr("data-test")
```

Explanation: inside the foreach loop you will get dom element since you are iterating list of dom element. So you cant invoke jquery method directly from dom elemet to do this you have to convert it into a jquery object to do this just use $(this)

Comment: `Try...` answers are not great. As you don't explain what you do and why it is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I added some explanation

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div[id!='t']").each(function(){
    $("#t").append($(this).data('data-test'));
}
```

Comment: `$("div[id!='t']")` ...?

Comment: The question is about `I try to find all elements with a particular attribute.`.

Comment: as he wants to add the `data-test` property only. So this each loop will select onlythose dive which dont have `id='t'` cz he is adding the attribute value in `$("t")` innnerHTML.

Comment: But it changes the meaning of the question. And in addition `$(this).data('data-test')`  won't work anyway, it should be either `$(this).attr('data-test')` or `$(this).data('test')`.

Comment: It is just an example. It will be integrated in a much more big file with different id's. So I don't think it is a good way.